# How to convert a NSString to long double?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsstring, double, long-double

I am dealing with a `long double` value that can have huge values.

At one time I have this number represented as `NSString` and I need to convert it to `long double`. I see that the only API I have is

```
[myString doubleValue];
```

I don't see a `longDoubleValue`.

Trying to convert this number using `doubleValue`...

```
long double x = (long double)[@"3765765765E933" doubleValue];
```

gives me `inf` and the number in question is a legit `long double` value, as these numbers can go up to `1.18973149535723176502E+4932`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Does NSDecimalNumber provide you with the precision you needed? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDecimalNumber

Comment: @chedabob NSDecimalNumber's exponent is limited to  between -127 and 127, his number is much larger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the answer of `mag_zbc` is almost there. The last line is incorrect.

Considering that the string has exponent, the correct is:

```
- (long double)longDoubleValue {
  NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"E"];
  long double mantis = (long double)[array[0] doubleValue];  
  long double exponent = (long double)[array[1] doubleValue];
  long double multiplier = powl(10.0L, exponent);
  return mantis * multiplier;
}
```

Comment: that is true, exponent is a power of 10

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps create a category on NSString yourself

```
NSArray *array = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"E"];
long double mantis = (long double)[array[0] doubleValue];
long double exponent = (long double)[array[1] doubleValue]; 
return mantis * exponent;
```

There will possibly be a loss of data though

**edit**
It would seem that `long double` on iOS is the same size as `double`. Maybe you will need a custom class to hold such large numbers.

Comment: I discovered that the last line is wrong. I have posted an answer to correct that. Thanks anyway. Upvoted.

Comment: that's true, apologies

Comment: no problem but you were in the right track. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do:

```
long double s = strtold(myString.UTF8String, NULL);
```

but if `sizeof(long double)` is the same as `sizeof(double)` as mag_zbc says, you might still get `Inf`.

If you want to go the `pow()` route, there is `powl()` which takes and returns `long double`s.

Comment: `powl`????? GREAT! for some reason I have searched for a pow for long double and failed to found... so I am improving my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the C library `sscanf` function. Here is a sample Objective-C wrapper:

```
long double stringToLongDouble(NSString *str)
{
   long double result = 0.0L;
   int ret = sscanf(str.UTF8String, "%Lg", &result);
   if (ret != 1)
   {
      // Insert your own error handling here, using NSLog for demo
      NSLog(@"stringToLongDouble: could not parse '%@' as long double", str);
      return 0.0L;
   }
   return result;
}
```

The return from `sscanf` will be `1` if it succeeds. For possible error returns see the documentation (`man 3 scanf` in Terminal) and you need to decide how to handle these, the above example just does an `NSLog`.

Note: The size & precision of `long double` may vary by platform/OS version. The above has been tested with your value on El Capitan and iOS 10 (simulator only) using Xcode 8.

HTH